# Toggle the class of a UL on an anchor click

Tags: jquery, css

I have a menu with the following structure [Code Pen Example](http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/cKbru):

```
<ul>
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/web-design">Web Design</a></li>
      <li><a href="/print-design">Print Design</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Help</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/by-email">By Email</a></li>
      <li><a href="/by-phone">By Phone</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="/about-us">About Us</a></li>
</ul>
```

When I click in Services or Help I would like to toggle the class of the next UL from and to "open" so I can show / hide the child menu.

When I open a child menu another child menu should be closed if there is any open.

I am using JQuery. How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the trick : **[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/flEis)**

```
 $("li a").click(function() {
     var element = $(this).next('ul');
     var flag = element.hasClass("open");
     $("li ul").removeClass("open");
     flag ? element.removeClass("open") : element.addClass("open");   
});
```

Comment: It does work very well ... For example, if you click services it open the child menu but if you click it again it does not close it.